# DocumentApp highlight NamedRange - use Comment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using [`NamedRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) a lot in my script and I would like to highlight it's position in document. I'm currently toggling background color of it via custom button, but this is not convenient.

I would like to implement such highlight, that will be visible in the app but won't print on paper. Such highlight has document comments. I'm not able to add such highlight, nor am able to add comment in the document via `AppsScript`, it seems that adding comments is not currently implemented.

Can you advice any solution?

Comment: It's correct that scripts cannot (yet) interact with comments. But they can [add and delete notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNote(String)), which are similar to comments. I don't know if notes appear when printed.

Comment: @Normal correct, but note is not available in [`DocumentApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app), only in [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)